# How to get the filename downloaded via wget after a redirect

Tags: linux, redirect, wget

I'm currently retrieving a file served after a redirection with the `--content-disposition` parameter, so the filename is the right filename (after redirection)

Now how can I retrieve the filename for future use in my shell script?

Comment: It should be in the `Content-Disposition` header of the response

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca does wget provide it to me in any way?

Comment: If you print the response headers with `-S` you can then grep it

Comment: Actually there's no `Content-Disposition` in the response, wget names the file according to the URI we're redirected to

Comment: Do I have to parse `Location` or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Consider that not all servers will give you a `Content-Disposition` header. Honestly I'm not sure how to get the final filename. If you want to use `Location` you'll have to get the last one before the final redirect, which you won't have if there are no redirects. I'd have to dig a bit into the http protocol to find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only direct way in the HTTP Spec for getting the filename is the `Content-Disposition` header. In the absence of that header, the client will usually deduce the name of the file based on the request URI.

In the case of Wget (assuming no `Content-Disposition` header exists), it will save the file with the name as mentioned in the URI of the original request. For example, if you invoke Wget with `http://example.com/afile` which redirects you to `http://example.com/bfile`, then the saved file will be called `afile`. This is a security measure to prevent a malicious server from overwriting other important files in your current directory, e.g. your `.bashrc`.

You can disable this behaviour with the `--trust-server-names` option, in which case it will save the file with the name `bfile`.

And then there is content-disposition. *If* it is enabled and the header exists, it will be used to name the file.

All this to say that the final name of the file is a little difficult to gauge. The easiest way is to save the file with `-O filename`, so you know the exact name of the file. If you don't want to do that, then the simplest option would be to invoke wget with the `-nv` option which outputs a line like this:

```
% wget -nv example.com                                                                                                 
2019-04-20 10:43:48 URL:http://example.com/ [1270/1270] -> "index.html" [1]
```

You can parse this output in order to get the name of the downloaded file.

Comment: This output is meant to be read by humans, it is difficult to parse and potentially prone to change, but I guess it's still the cleaner solution

Comment: Actually the output will not change. It is a little difficult to parse, I agree. But as the maintainer of Wget, let me tell you, we make every effort possible to ensure that the output doesn't change since we know that scripts tend to parse it. Only the `--debug` output can change arbitrarily

Comment: Ok. Just for my information, do you know why wget does not provide an easiest solution for my problem? Is there something on the roadmap?

Comment: What would be an easier solution? We already provide a relatively easy way for you to parse the output and get the information you want. How would you prefer it?

Comment: Nevermind, as you told be the output was not likely to change, I parse it with a regexp. Thanks!